# TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound error starting Rails v4.1.0 server on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1, tzinfo

I have created a new application using Ruby on Rails v4.1.0. When attempting to start a server or console on Windows, I am encountering the following error:

```
$ rails server
Booting WEBrick
Rails 4.1.0 application starting in development on ....

Exiting
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:199:
in `rescue in create_default_data_source': 
No timezone data source could be found. To resolve this, either install 
TZInfo::Data (e.g. by running `gem install tzinfo-data`) or specify a zoneinfo 
directory using `TZInfo::DataSource.set(:zoneinfo, zoneinfo_path)`.
(TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound) 
from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:196:
in `create_default_data_source'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Hove you done what the error suggests? ie "`gem install tzinfo-data` or specify a zoneinfo directory using `TZInfo::DataSource.set(:zoneinfo, zoneinfo_path)". If so, what was the result?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

**Resolving the Error**

To resolve this error, you'll need to make sure that the tzinfo-data gem is being included in your `Gemfile`.

First of all, check your `Gemfile` to see if there is an existing reference to `tzinfo-data`. If there isn't already a reference, then add the following line:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

You may find that there is already a line like the following:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

If you are using a 64-bit version of Ruby on Windows, then add `:x64_mingw` to the list of platforms as follows:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `platforms` option altogether.

Note that there is a [bug in Bundler](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/5269) that means there's currently no platform option that will match 64-bit Ruby 3.1 on Windows. The solution here to remove the `platforms` option.

After doing this, run `bundle update` at the command line to install the tzinfo-data gem and you'll then be able to start your Rails server or console.

**Background**

The `TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound` error is being raised by TZInfo, a dependency of the Active Support component of Rails. TZInfo is looking for a source of time zone data on your system, but failing to find one.

On many Unix-based systems (e.g. Linux), TZInfo is able to use the system [zoneinfo](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) directory as a source of data. However, Windows doesn't include such a directory, so the tzinfo-data gem needs to be installed instead. The tzinfo-data gem contains the same zoneinfo data, packaged as a set of Ruby modules.

Rails generates a default `Gemfile` when the application is first created. If the application is created on Windows, then a dependency for tzinfo-data will be included. However Rails (up to version 4.1.x) omitted `:x64_mingw` from the list of platforms and therefore didn't work correctly on 64-bit Windows versions of Ruby.

Comment: Does `tzinfo-data` have to be in the Gemfile permanently or just until the Rails team fixes something?

Comment: @MarkBoulder You'll need to keep `tzinfo-data` in your Gemfile permanently if you want to run your Rails project on Windows.

Comment: I'm on OpenBSD, seems I need it there too. Hopefully it's already in the Gemfile for newly generated Rails apps?

Comment: @MarkBoulder `tzinfo-data` is required at the moment on OpenBSD because the current version of TZInfo [is not able to use OpenBSD's system zoneinfo directory](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/issues/15). There's a [fix](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/commit/cd3377fdeef462be26366e103e486ffdaf788e23) in the git repository. This will be included in the next TZInfo release.

Comment: TZInfo [v1.2.0 has now been released](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/releases/tag/v1.2.0). This includes the fix for loading zoneinfo files on BSD and Solaris.

Comment: From https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors

Comment: how do add docker to the platform list when using alpine?

Comment: @Blankman you can run [`bundle platform`](https://bundler.io/v1.16/man/bundle-platform.1.html) to determine the current platform.

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me in modern times, instead I had to replace `gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]`
with
`gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2021', '>= 1.2021.5'`

Comment: @DrQuarius if you're using Ruby 3.1 on Windows, then you might be encountering a bug in Bundler: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/5269. There's no platform option that will match 64-bit Ruby 3.1 on Windows. The solution is to remove the platforms option (the version constraints aren't needed).

Comment: Thank you, @PhilRoss!!! Removing the platforms option worked. Saved me some time there. Much appreciated.

Comment: Rails requires 'tzinfo', so you don't need to include it in your Gemfile for a Rails application.  I found that on Rails 7.x, commenting out the platforms; %i[...] resolved the issue.

Answer (score 16):

I had to add two gems to get the server to start..

gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'tzinfo'

Then bundle install.

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me in modern times, instead I had to replace `gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]`
with
`gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2021', '>= 1.2021.5'`

Answer (score 16):

I had that error when trying to install Redmine in a Docker container:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

gave me the error because package `tzdata` was not installed in my Ubuntu image.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install tzdata -y
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 9):

Just put this in your app terminal :

```
gem install tzinfo-data
```

then change the gemfile line to :

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:x64_mingw, :mingw, :mswin]
```

then again in your terminal :

```
bundle update
```

That will solve the problem directly.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following line to your Gem File

> gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:x64_mingw,:mingw, :mswin]

Answer (score 4):

In **Gemfile**, I added this following line

```
#tzinfo-data
gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2021', '>= 1.2021.5'
```

and then, I commented out the following line

```
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]
```

and then I simply ran

```
rails server
```

and it worked for me successfully.

Here is my full **Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.1.1"

#tzinfo-data
gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2021', '>= 1.2021.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.2", ">= 7.0.2.3"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "webdrivers"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe tzinfo is not installed on your system, try to install it:

```
 gem install tzinfo
 gem install tzinfo-data
```

Comment: Also add "gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]" into "\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\railties-4.1.6\lib\rails\generators\rails\app\templates\Gemfile" file. Then this will be added to all new apps by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and fixed it by adding BOTH the `:x64_mingw` to the list of platforms for `tzinfo-data`, AND the gem 'tzinfo' to the gemfile. Then bundle install.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue on macOs Mojave 10.14.5 and I found out that it was something with how my symlink in macOs wasn't reading the correct provided zone info files.

I was able to track this down with where the files should be using the command 
`TZInfo::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path` and that provided the output of `["/usr/share/zoneinfo", "/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo", "/etc/zoneinfo"]`.

I began looking into `/usr/share/zoneinfo` and there were files available to read. However rails still wasn't finding them, reading them, executing them..? So I then created a symlink from the other file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo.default/` to `/etc/zoneinfo` (the last path TZInfo looks up)

So finally the command that worked for me to fix this issue was `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo.default /etc/zoneinfo`

Hopefully this information is helpful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that installing the gem directly via cmd might not solve the issue on Windows OS.
Here is how it did work for me step-by-step;

1. Inside the Gemfile folder "ctrl-F" and type "platforms"
2. Find the line gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin
   x64_mingw jruby ]
3. Remove everything after "tzinfo-data" (comma included)
4. Final view should be just *gem "tzinfo-data"* add also *gem "tzinfo"*
5. On the terminal, type "bundler update" or "bundle update"
6. Once it is completed, type "rails s"

*Notice*: Even after this, if your server starts but can not resolve the default page (additionally *ctrl-c* / *ctrl-pause/break* doesn't work), then add **webrick** instead of **puma** by adding the gem `gem 'webrick', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'`. After that, to run the webrick server you need to type
`rails s -u webrick`

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows and for several days I was not able to solve this problem.
So the solution for our 64 bit platform is to type the following in the terminal:

```
gem install tzinfo
gem install tzinfo-data
```

Then afterwards go navigate back to your **gem file**. In case if you haven't created one create it with rails new xyznameofyours on the terminal.

Then replace the line of code which states something like:
<s>gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]</s>  or
<s>gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]</s>
to this:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'tzinfo'
```

Only then after your code will work!

Answer (score 0):

1-go to gemfile
add the following line without any arrays only that line
**gem "tzinfo-data"**
then save the file

2- then on cmd type
**bundle install**
then press Enter

3-then also on cmd type
**rails server**
then press Enter

Answer (score -1):

so, the gems didn't quite seem to install properly, i had to do the following

gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'tzinfo'

then

> bundle show
>   to see all gems
>
> bundle gem tzinfo 
>   will get you the gem's directory

then, go to that directory. you will need to splice tzinfo-data into tzinfo.
in the tzinfo-data file, go to..
local_pathname/tzinfo-data-1.2014.5/lib/tzinfo
copy all the contents of this directory into...
local_pathname/tzinfo-1.2.1/lib/tzinfo
(for me this meant copying 'data' the file and 'data' the directory)

then
go to 
local_pathname/tzinfo-1.2.1/lib
and open the file, tzinfo, (not the directory)
and add this line
require 'tzinfo/data'

this was such a pain to figure out

Answer (score -1):

I've replaced:

```
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]
```

with:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2021', '>= 1.2021.5'
```

and it worked fine.

```
> Blockquote
```