# Trouble Installing Bootstrap on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-sass

I am trying to install Bootstrap on Rails but can't seem to get it installed. I have ran `bundle install` , `bundle update` and `rails server` but just can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the error code:

> File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
>   Load paths:
>   c:/Users/teddynuts/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/images
>   c:/Users/teddynuts/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/javascripts
>   c:/Users/teddynuts/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/stylesheets
>   c:/Users/teddynuts/Desktop/pinteresting/vendor/assets/javascripts
>   c:/Users/teddynuts/Desktop/pinteresting/vendor/assets/stylesheets
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-2.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1/lib/assets/javascripts
>         (in c:/Users/teddynuts/Desktop/pinteresting/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss:1)

My CSS file titled `bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss` code is:

```
    @import "bootstrap";
```

My Gem file code is:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'  
gem 'bootstrap-sass',

group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Comment: `gem 'bootstrap-sass',` - extra coma

Comment: When I remove the comma, GitBash says `Gemfile syntax error: group:  : doc`

Comment: The group:
should be something like this:
https://gist.github.com/lyc4n/1c04c11dbb3e3fa9cef9

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign something to your "group". What goes into `group :doc` ?

I see that you are  taking the One Month Rails Tutorial, so the gemfile for the Lesson *(Until bootstrap)* should be this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

# Gems for Local Development
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Gems for Heroku
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

[Official Sass port of Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

Sometimes when you are stuck just give the [Official Repo](https://github.com/onemonthrails/pinteresting) a look.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your advice. I replaced my entire Gem file with what you have, but when I try to start my Rails server with `rails server` in Gitbash, it auto closes down immediately, so I am not sure how to proceed. Could you help? Thanks

Comment: Did you include your Rails Gem ?

Comment: Yup I did but still no luck

Comment: Where am I supposed to include the Rails gem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass',

group: :doc
```

It may not be obvious, but it's **one** statement. In fact, it's interpreted like this:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', { :group => :doc }
```

...and therefore the specified gem is only available during docs generation. And the solution for this exact issue is to replace the above with:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

However, since you're on Windows (if it's x64, which is likely), you may run into other issues, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022258/tzinfodatasourcenotfound-error-starting-rails-v4-1-0-server-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Try bootstrap-sass-rails instead. It works in the asset pipeline. https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails