# rails server issue (rails 4.1.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tzinfo

I'm a beginer in RoR and I am having a really bad time trying to make the rails server work. everytime i run the command

```
rails server
```

It allways shows all this lines

```
    C:\Users\Familia-PC\RoR\holamundo>rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0
.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:1
99:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': No timezone data source could be f
ound. To resolve this, either install TZInfo::Data (e.g. by running `gem install
 tzinfo-data`) or specify a zoneinfo directory using `TZInfo::DataSource.set(:zo
neinfo, zoneinfo_path)`. (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/dat
a_source.rb:196:in `create_default_data_source'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/dat
a_source.rb:62:in `block in get'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/dat
a_source.rb:61:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/dat
a_source.rb:61:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/tim
ezone.rb:601:in `data_source'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/tim
ezone.rb:114:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/tim
ezone_proxy.rb:84:in `real_timezone'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/tim
ezone_proxy.rb:52:in `period_for_utc'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/tim
ezone.rb:524:in `current_period'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/act
ive_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:45:in `public_send'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/act
ive_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:45:in `try'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/act
ive_support/values/time_zone.rb:223:in `utc_offset'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/act
ive_support/values/time_zone.rb:396:in `block in []'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/act
ive_support/values/time_zone.rb:396:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/act
ive_support/values/time_zone.rb:396:in `[]'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/act
ive_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:60:in `find_zone!'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/act
ive_support/railtie.rb:20:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'

        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in
each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connec
ted_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strong
ly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connec
ted_component'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:288:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/Familia-PC/RoR/holamundo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top
(required)>'
        from C:/Users/Familia-PC/RoR/holamundo/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Familia-PC/RoR/holamundo/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder
.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder
.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/Familia-PC/RoR/holamundo/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Users/Familia-PC/RoR/holamundo/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder
.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder
.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder
.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.
rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.
rb:199:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/co
mmands/server.rb:50:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.
rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/co
mmands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/co
mmands/server.rb:67:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I hope you guys can help me solve this problem

Comment: You are not the only person having this problem. This won't be your favorite answer, but going back to a stable release of `Rails 4.1` might help. `gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git", :branch => "4-1-stable"`. That being said, I have seen a few people fix this problem using @Matheus's answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound error starting Rails v4.1.0 server on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022258/tzinfodatasourcenotfound-error-starting-rails-v4-1-0-server-on-windows)

Comment: same problem to me how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your gemfile:

```
gem "tzinfo-data"
```

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted. That's a possible solution to his/her problem.

Comment: ... as it already says in the error message, I would like to add. ;-)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my gem file already had it. anyway i found a solution, I just had to add :x64_mingw to the gem "tzinfo-data" array.

Comment: `:x64_mingw` is an invalid option