# Ruby on Rails can't connect to localhost:3000, 127.0.0.1:3000 and 0.0.0.0:3000 on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tzinfo

I'm a total newbie learning Ruby on Rails and using a Windows machine. The steps used to install ruby on rails were:

1. download ruby200-x64 installer for Windows
2. then run the following commands

   - `ruby dk.rb init`
   - `ruby dk.rb install`
   - `gem install bundler`
   - `gem install sqlite3`
   - `gem install rails`
   - `rails new testapp`
   - `cd testapp`
   - `bundle exec rails server` which means that I ran rails server in the testapp folder and part of the output says this:

     - Booting WEBrick
     - Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on 0.0.0.0:3000
     - Run rails server -h for more startup options
     - Notice: server is listening on all interfaces 0.0.0.0. Consider using 127.0.0.1
     - Ctrl-C to shutdown server
     - Exiting
     - C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.1/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb: No source of timezone data could be found. Please refer to http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving this error
     - Follow by more lines of codes (sorry, didn't have enough reputation points to post an image.
3. Finally when I tried to connect to localhost:3000, 127.0.0.1:3000, or 0.0.0.0:3000. None worked. Any ideas? I'm guessing it has to do something with the Exiting line.

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow!
Don't worry about posting extra code - in fact it's much better than posting an image (because then people can copy/paste bits to reply to).

Comment: possible duplicate of [TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound error starting Rails v4.1.0 server on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022258/tzinfodatasourcenotfound-error-starting-rails-v4-1-0-server-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error indicates that TZInfo was unable to find a source of time
>   zone data on your system. This will typically occur if you are using
>   Windows.

[Resolving TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound Errors](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo%3a%3aDataSourceNotFound-Errors)

Try to install tzinfo-data gem by editing `Gemfile` and put `gem 'tzinfo-data'` and run `bundle install`

Or to use the ruby modules as the data source, running by

`gem install tzinfo-data`