# cant install ruby on rails 1.9.3 on windows 8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-8.1, require, pty

After many tries, i give up. this  message keeps on appearing when i try to run ROR after creating a new  project :

```
C:\Ruby193\test_1>rails s
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/slave.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web-console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/test_1/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

will someone help me figure out what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have to do when installing a rails environment, is to install the bundler itself

```
rails bundler install
```

Answer (score 0):

[rails installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en) by engine yard will be an easy solution for you with all the necessary packages .

they also provide version packaged with ruby 1.9.3 [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-2.2.5.exe)

---

**common problems on windows**

if you are using 2.0 + following threads will be relevant .

[TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound error starting Rails v4.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022258/tzinfodatasourcenotfound-error-starting-rails-v4-1-0-server-on-windows)

[Can't access RubyGems SSL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364008/cant-access-rubygems-possibly-due-to-ssl)

[“DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle” warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590450/ruby-2-0-0p0-irb-error-dl-is-deprecated-please-use-fiddle)