# Can't access RubyGems - possibly due to SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rubygems

New Ruby on Rails dev here, just trying to install and get set up.

I'm following [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on how to get started. However, when I get to 3.2 Creating the Blog Application, I run into an issue when I run `rails new blog`. When I try that, I get an error that says

> An error occurred while installing rake 10.4.2, and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2'' succeeds before bundling.

So, when I try to run that command, I get this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rake': Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0  state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

After Googling around, I found [this guide](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html). During the diagnosis portion, I tried running `openssl version`, which didn't work. I installed OpenSSL and added it to my path. However, I still get the same error when I try to fetch any gems. I also can't ping rubygems.org - nothing comes back.

I'm using Windows 7, Rails 4.1.8, Ruby 2.0.0p598, RubyGems 2.0.14, and OpenSSL 1.01j. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a quick solution:

Go to your gem file and change

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org' #remove the 's'
```

Check this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error) on StackOverflow for more solutions and insights into the error :)

### **Edit:**

Based on inputs by @Anthony in the comments below, here is a more permanent solution :

Download : [AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem).(Note: File must have .pem as extension. Browsers like Chrome will try to save it as plain text file. Ensure you change the filename to have .pem in it after you have downloaded it.)

Now Run the following in your command prompt:

```
C:\>gem which rubygems
```

Thiw will give you a path where you need to place the above `.pem` file. Navigate inside the directory to which the path  points. Inside it locate `ssl_certs` directory and copy the .pem file we obtained from previous step inside.

This shall do the trick!

Comment: this will work but `http` calls to rubygems are deprecated so this will break eventually.

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks for the info! I wasn't aware of this! Updating the answer based on you inputs! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm having trouble keeping it as a .pem - as you said, Chrome downloads it as a .txt. How can I force it or convert it to the correct pem extension?

Comment: Do this: First open this download link in a new tab. Go to the directory where this file is required to be stored. Then create a text file in that directory and copy the contents from the new tab into this text file. Rename this text file to the name of the pem file (AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem) and remove the .txt extension at the end.

Comment: Seems to have done it. I'm having other issues with some gem stuff, but I think this solved this problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem: the link  mentioned above is broken.. does anyone know the right one ?

Comment: you can download this pem file from here `https://github.com/smalruby/smalruby-installer-for-windows/blob/master/Ruby216_32/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem` copying it in `ssl_certs` doesn't solve problem for not even using `http://` instead of `https://`

Answer (score 19):

It's specific to a windows permission issue, you can read the entire scope of the issue [here](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88)

For the tl;dr -

**Step 1: Obtain the new trust certificate**

Download: [AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/index.rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA.pem)

**Step 2: Locate RubyGems certificate directory in your installation**

```
C:\>gem which rubygems
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
```

We want to open the path listed above:

```
C:\>start C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\2.1.0\rubygems
```

**Step 3: Copy new trust certificate**

Now, locate `ssl_certs` directory and copy the `.pem` file we obtained from step 1 inside.

Comment: Hi Anothony, thanks for your response. I could only get the file as a .pem.der file using this utility: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html and it still didn't seem to work, I'm still having the same issue. Do I need a .pem file strictly?

Comment: it has to retain a .pem file extension so make sure it stays that way (for instance windows might try and rename it)

Comment: This should be the right answer. THANKS

Comment: The link is broken.