# Make sure that 'gem install ~ ' succeeds before bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I began learning Ruby on rails today.
I have installed Ruby, DEVELOPMENT KIT, SQLite3, bundler and rails.

Next, My textbook says to run `rails new todo` in the console. Then, the following message appeared:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing execjs (2.2.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install execjs -v '2.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I did as follows.

```
C:\rubyfolder>gem install execjs -v 2.2.2
```

Then it appeared as follows:

```
Fetching: execjs-2.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed execjs-2.2.2
Parsing documentation for execjs-2.2.2
Installing ri documentation for execjs-2.2.2
Done installing documentation for execjs after 1 seconds
WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
1 gem installed
```

Next, I ran `rails new todo` again. Then, the message that `execjs` of above message is replaced by `coffee-script` appeared.

```
Make sure that `gem install coffee-script -v '2.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Next, I installed coffee-script.

I have repeated this kind of work for 3 or 4 times, but it don't finish. What should I do?

(`execjs` might not be the first of this cycle. I can't see first part of logs)

Comment: It might be related to the SSL issue which is a windows thing.  Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364008/cant-access-rubygems-possibly-due-to-ssl/27364329#27364329) on the subject and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I check that.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced similar kind of issue. This is what worked for me:

1. In your `Gemfile` or wherever you have specified the gems list and  replace `source 'https://......'` with this `source 'http://.......'` otherwise it will keep on asking `Make sure that gem install gem_name__ v xxx'` succeeds before bundling.`
2. Do `bundle install` or `rails new todo`
3. Done, no error this time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to run `gem install` separatly doesn't solve the root of the problem. Looks like you didn't install all needed development dependencies for Rails. Try to complete libraries within [official instruction](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/development_dependencies_install.html).

Also I see from you path you try it on Windows and probably you need to install dependencies this way, cause official documentation doesn't provide instructions for this OS:
`gem install rails --include-dependencies`

Comment: When I ran     gem install, it appeared as follows.ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    invalid option: --include-dependencies