# bundle install fails due to certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler, bitnami

I have installed ruby on windows using bitnami Ruby Stack, then when I run bundle install, I get

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.3.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any idea?

Comment: check out my answer to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364008/cant-access-rubygems-possibly-due-to-ssl/27364329#27364329)

Comment: thank you! vote+ to your answer :)

Comment: can you please see the EDIT above?

Comment: Are you using vapybara-webkit? If yes, have you installed Qt?

Comment: I am not using vapybara-webkit, I am installing Qt now ..

Comment: Qt is big, what exactly do I need from Qt? I think only MinGW 4.8, about 600 MB..

Comment: If you solved your first problem, then you can't add an additional one to your question. Stack Overflow questions are supposed to be for a single question, *maybe* two, and very seldom three unless they are all very closely related. Asking a second question dilutes the value of the first question for future people searching for answers to the same question. So, don't ask a new one, create a new question, and either delete this one if no answer was submitted, or, if you solved the problem yourself, create an answer documenting the fix, select it as the answer, and ask a new question.

Comment: I am sorry, you are absolutely right, I just felt a bit lazy, and I wanted to catch up with the developers

Comment: I've just removed the second question