# Gem install error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I get this message:

> An error occurred  while installing **rake <10.4.2>**, and bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `'gem install rake -v '10.4.2'`
>   succeeds before installing.

How should I proceed to fix this error?

Comment: run this command in terminal 
gem install rake -v '10.4.2'

Comment: This kind of question has been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364008/cant-access-rubygems-possibly-due-to-ssl

Answer (score 0):

run the follwing in terminal
gem install rake -v '10.4.2'

if it shows error
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle update
bundle install

cheers :)-