# Migrating from Trac to Redmine [Trac2Redmine]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, trac, migrate

**Jump below for solution with Stable Release. Currently I am working on an older release of redmine with older ruby, and finally made it work, my question is still a question though, still all kind of answers & comments are accepted!**

Lately i am trying to move my trac.db to redmine, and i have faced so many bugs etc.

I want to ask is there any stable version of Redmine for migrating, or any good patched migrate_from_trac.rake file?

Currently i have:
Redmine 3.2.3
Ruby 2.2.0

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
gem "rails", "4.2.5.2"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.4"
gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "builder", ">= 3.0.4"
gem "request_store", "1.0.5"
gem "mime-types", (RUBY_VERSION >= "2.0" ? "~> 3.0" : "~> 2.99")
gem "protected_attributes"
gem "actionpack-action_caching"
gem "actionpack-xml_parser"
gem "roadie-rails"
gem "mimemagic"
gem 'arel', '6.0.0.beta2'
gem "activerecord-deprecated_finders", require: "active_record/deprecated_finders"
```

Is there anything else you need i will happily answer them too.

My final error is:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "AND": syntax error: SELECT  "session_attribute".* FROM "session_attribute" WHERE "session_attribute"."sid" =  AND "session_attribute"."name" =  LIMIT 1
```

Please answer or ask something, I will return you in 15 hours in worst case.

(This is my first question, so i am open for any comments, sorry for my bad english)

**change.log: migrate_from_trac.rake**

```
Fixed: set_inheritance_column & set_primary_key errors.

Fixed: add 'gem' sqlite3 to your Gemfile error.

Fixed: incorrect date time value between trac and redmine.
```

**Stable Release Solution**

Redmine-3.1.1

Ruby-2.1.5

*after you installed these, we can start.

you can also get help from these two links from redmine itself:

[Redmine Install](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redmineinstall)

[Redmine Migrate](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineMigrate)

**My Guide for proper setup:**

**i.** Edit your database (Use database.yml)

**ii.** add this to your gemfile

```
gem "activerecord-deprecated_finders", require:active_record/deprecated_finders"
```

**iii.** add AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem to your ruby:
[Can't access RubyGems - Due to SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364008/cant-access-rubygems-possibly-due-to-ssl)

**iv.** We are having trouble with generating secret token, We need to install some gems:

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.4
gem install jquery-rails -v 3.1.3
gem install protected_attributes
gem install actionpack-action_caching
gem install actionpack-xml_parser
gem install tzinfo-data
gem install rbpdf -v 1.18.6
gem install rack-openid
```

then again:

```
bundle install
```

**v.** If mysql server stopped.
open `services.msc` then start

> MYSQL56

service from the list.

**vi.** If asks sqlite3, `gem install sqlite3-ruby`

**vii.** `rake redmine:migrate_from_trac RAILS_ENV=production` there you go!

```
Trac directory []: /var/trac/myproject
Trac database adapter (sqlite, sqlite3, mysql, postgresql) [sqlite]:
Database encoding [UTF-8]:
Target project identifier []: myproject
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
Deleting data
Migrating components..............................
Migrating milestones..............
Migrating custom fields.......
Migrating tickets.................................
Migrating wiki...........

Components: 29/30
Milestones: 14/14
Tickets: 1275/1275
Ticket files: 106/106
Custom values: 4409/4409
Wiki edits: 102/102
```

**The result I get:**

[image: result]

> Migration code isn't working fully yet.

**NOTE:** if you get sqlite3 error about gemfile, add your gemfile: `gem 'sqlite3'` and you are done.