# PG pg_ext load error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pg

I recently updated to rails 4.1.6 and ruby 2.1.3p242. I also updated all gems on my system. After creating a new app, I keep getting a pg_ext load file error on running the server. I'm on windows 8 x64 with PostgreSQL 9.3. The pg gem was working fine under my previous RoR installation which was rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3.

Under the gem's installation directory, I've a 2.0/pg_ext.so file. I tried renaming the folder to 2.1 and ran the server. The result was the same. I assume it's cause Ruby doesn't allow to Require a .so file. Below is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to reinstall the pg gem under ruby 2.1

Comment: I tried doing that. Did not work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posted question on the official Gem page:

https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/192/pg_ext-load-error

As per the suggestion, I installed the pre-version of the next release. That gave me another error which was solved using:

https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors
[TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound error starting Rails v4.1.0 server on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022258/tzinfodatasourcenotfound-error-starting-rails-v4-1-0-server-on-windows)

Posting the answer to help people facing similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Using pre-release version solved the issue, for now. Cheers.

Comment: No problems. I'm using it for Dev and testing too. Hopefully, they'll release the next stable version soon.

Answer (score 6):

1) In the command line enter:

```
gem install pg --pre
gem list pg
```

2) In the Gemfile set the gem to the newly installed version:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.2'
```