# Rails server no source of timezone data could be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler

I am working on a project team with ruby on rails,
the project was created on MAC OSX and I use windows.
When I try to start the server with `rails server`, I have this error : `Rails server no source of timezone data could be found`

I do a `bundle install` and after a `gem install tzinfo-data, then I have the same error again.

How can I solve this problem and launch my server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound error starting Rails v4.1.0 server on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022258/tzinfodatasourcenotfound-error-starting-rails-v4-1-0-server-on-windows)

Comment: i have already try what is proposed the problem is not resolve

Comment: Have you added the gem `tz-info` too, which other people said they need to do?