# failed to build rails server cause of tzinfo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tzinfo

i already add gem 'tzinfo-data' on my gemfile but its keep saying please add tzinfo-data when I make rails server.

Is it because of the rails that I install or ruby that I install, or maybe there is some step that I missing?

```html
C:\Users\LENOVO 330S-15ARR\sample_app>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.2.3 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:159:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:156:in `create_default_data_source'        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:55:in `block in get'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.4/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `get'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/3.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Users/LENOVO 330S-15ARR/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
```

[the picture of error cause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m6zt.png)

how can I solve this error?

Comment: what happens when you run "bundle install"?

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: aah thanks Mr.Jared, i think it's solved.
last night I try add gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw] on gemfile, and its show errors like that, then I change the line with just gem 'tzinfo-data' and its working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tzinfo-data present but not seen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486891/tzinfo-data-present-but-not-seen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [bug in Bundler](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/5269) that means there's no valid platform value that will match 64-bit Ruby 3.1 on Windows.

If the `gem 'tzinfo-data` line in your `Gemfile` includes a `platforms` option, Bundler will exclude tzinfo-data from the bundle and you'll get the `TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound` error.

The solution is to remove the `platforms` option from the tzinfo-data line in the Gemfile and then run `bundle install`:

```rb
gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the gemfile contains `gem "`tzinfo-data" and then bundle install.

Just ensure the gem is platform independent