# Issues regarding new Ruby On Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I attempted to make a new app using `rails new` command and the bundle is completed. However, it said that `rails aborted!` and appeared another error:

```
Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 70 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  importmap:install
rails aborted!
TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install
C:/Sites/test_001/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'

Caused by:
TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound: None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories.
C:/Sites/test_001/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => app:template => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
```

Any help on resolving this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Ruby 3.1? There's a [bug](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/5269) that stops the default Rails `Gemfile` from including tzinfo-data. Try changing the tzinfo-data line in your `Gemfile` to just `gem 'tzinfo-data'` and running `bundle install`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71654030/5981

Answer (score 3):

It says that you need to install **tzinfo-data** gem for your application.
Please add

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2021', '>= 1.2021.5'
```

in your application's gemfile.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I've mixed two of the answers here and it fixed the problem for me on Windows 11.

I've added:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2021', '>= 1.2021.5'
```

And removed the other part of the `gem 'tzinfo-data'` added by default.

Answer (score 1):

In the gem fille where you see gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ], remove platforms and then run gem install tzinfo-data. After you do that run bundle install. Then go back to the original directory where you ran rails new, and run it again with the same name, I managed to get rid of the tzinfo error and the node(package.json) error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).