# How to solve tzinfo error on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cmd, rubygems, project, tzinfo

Trying to learn ruby on rails and I keep coming up with this error:

```
rails aborted!
TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install
Caused by:
TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound: None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories.
D:/RubyRails/ineedhelp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => app:template => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
```

when I'm starting a new project

I'm using Windows 10 64bit.

Though I keep adding `gem "tzinfo-data"` to my application's GemFile AND use `gem install tzinfo` in cmd, it doesn't work.
It may work temporarily but the error keeps showing up each time I'm trying to insert another command in cmd (like `rails s`).

```
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]
```

This line is already in my GemFile when the error pops up.
I already tried several solutions found online.

Comment: Are you using 64-bit Ruby 3.1? There's a [bug](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/5269) that stops the default Rails `Gemfile` from including tzinfo-data. Try changing the tzinfo-data line in your `Gemfile` to just `gem 'tzinfo-data'` and running `bundle install`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71654030/5981

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I deleted the platforms line and it seems to be working for now! I use 64 bit Ruby 3.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tzinfo-data present but not seen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486891/tzinfo-data-present-but-not-seen)

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the platform part
This is how your gem name should look like

```
 gem "tzinfo-data"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can install `tzdata` package on Debian

```
apt install tzdata
```