# Rails server failed because tzinfo-data is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tzinfo

I'm using Ruby 3.1.2 on Windows(x64) and I'm trying to run rails server and connect to localhost:3000.

I execute `rails s` in cmd (while directing to the folder created by `rails new`), but the message shows `tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)`

Then, I open the Gemfile in .txt and write this line: `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]`

I also do `bundle install` after that.

But when I do `rails server` again, it still shows the same message saying that tzinfo-data is not present.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Millions of thanks if someone can solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tzinfo-data present but not seen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71486891/tzinfo-data-present-but-not-seen)

Answer (score 0):

There's a [bug in Bundler](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/5269) that means there's no valid platform value that will match 64-bit Ruby 3.1 on Windows.

With `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]` in your `Gemfile` (or any `platforms` option), Bundler will exclude tzinfo-data from the bundle and you'll get the `TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound` error.

The solution is to remove the `platforms` option from the tzinfo-data line in the Gemfile and then run `bundle install`:

```rb
gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

Comment: OMG it really worked! Finally